# The correspondence between affine varieties and K-algebra homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the book :"Algebraic Geometry" of Andreas Gathemann,Lemma 2.3.7, it says:

Let X $\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and Y $\subset \mathbb{A}^m$  be affine varieties. There is a one-to-one correspondence between morphisms $f : X \rightarrow$  Y and k-algebra homomorphisms $f^{*} : A(Y) \rightarrow
A(X)$

In the second part of the proof it says:

Conversely, if:

$$g:K[y_1,...,y_m]/I(Y) \rightarrow K[x_1,...,x_n]/I(X) $$
is any k-algebra homomorphism then it determines a polynomial map $f = ( f_1,..., f_m) :
X \rightarrow Y$ by $f_i = g(y_i)$, and hence a morphism.

Now my question is:

Why the image of $f$ is in $Y$ ?

Comment: I was always a bit confused with this proof and I think something is not very clear. Here are two useful observations : 1) $z \in Y$ iff for all $\phi \in I(Y), \phi(z) = 0$, 2) $g$ commutes with any polynomial and $g(\phi) = 0$ for all $\phi \in I(Y)$ since it's defined on $k[y]/I(Y)$. With this the proof should go like $\phi(f(y)) = g(\phi(y) = g(0) = 0$ but I'm not sure this is very formal.

Comment: You should try the case $k[X] = k[x]/(u(x)),k[Y] = k[y]/(v(y))$ where the varieties are defined by a single polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y$ is an algebraic variety, $V(I(Y)) = Y$. So it suffices to prove $f(X) \subset V(I(Y))$. 
As was pointed out in the comments, $z \in V(I(Y)) \iff \phi(z) = 0$ for all $\phi \in I(Y)$. Let $h = h_nZ^n + \dots + h_0 \in I(Y)$. 
Then $(h \circ f)(x) = h(g(y_1)(x), \dots, g(y_m)(x)) = h_n(g(y_1)(x))^n + \dots +  h_0$.
Now using the fact that $g$ is, by assumption a K-algebra homomorphism (that is: a K-linear ring homomorphism) you can rewrite this as $g(h_0(y_1)^n(x) + \dots  + h_0) = g(h)(x)$. Now it suffices to observe that each element $h$ of $I(Y)$ is the $0$ element in $A(Y)$ so that $g(h) = 0$.